# Convert a value string in metatable to table for lookup

Tags: lua

I have an enormous table of functions named engine_api with inline documentation.  Because it's becoming so large I'd like to make it more modular.

The api is set up like this:

```
-- Engine API module
local engine_api = {
  engine = {
     -- engine functions...
     version = ...
  },

  image = {
     -- image functions...

     jpeg = {
       -- jpeg specific bits
     },
  },

  project = {
    -- project functions
  }
}

return engine_api
```

As you can see, it's more than 2 levels deep.
The whole thing is returned as a single table so other parts of the system can call into this api like this:

```
local api = require "engine_api"

print("Engine version:", engine_api.engine.version());
```

I still need it to work this way.  But what I'd like to do is separate various parts of the API into different files.  I thought I might be able to do this using metamethods.  But when the metamethod is looked up, the value is actually a string so this naive approach will not work.

```
local engine = {
  -- engine functions...
  version = function()
    print("engine.version")
  end
}

local image = {
  -- image functions
  get = function()
    print("image.get")
  end
}

local project = {
  -- project functions
  load = function()
    print("project.load()")
  end
}

-- Engine API module
local engine_api = {

}

local engine_api_mt = {
  __index = function(tbl, k)
    print("k=", k)
    return k
  end
}

setmetatable(engine_api, engine_api_mt)
```

Instead I seem to have to do bunch of if then else statements to compare the table name with the string and then return the table and not the string.  Is there a way of performing the conversion automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `engine_api` a single file and require files inside that table, like so:

engine_api.lua:

```
local engine_api = {
    engine = require("engine"),
    image = require("image"),
    project = require("project"),
} 

return engine_api
```

engine.lua:

```
local engine = {
    version = function()
        print("my version")
    end
}

return engine
```

And so on, that way you can call `engine_api.engine.version()` with no problems at all. I think the metatable is just over the top, unless you are doing something more specific?

Comment: Doh! it's so darn obvious now.  Thanks Basilio!

Comment: Anytime. Been working on a similar project for some time now.